# ioctl(2) codes in kernel for hard disks

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Where are the ioctl(2) list of codes for a hard disk partition in the linux kernel source? I can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 1):

The list of available ioctls depends upon the particular components in the chain:

1. generic file ioctls (`FIBMAP`, etc.) — most likely they are not applicable to block devs, but they are there anyway. See `include/linux/fs.h` for the list of `FI*` macros.
2. generic block layer ioctl (`BLKRRPART`, etc.) — see `fs.h` too
3. filesystem-specific ioctls (e.g. `REISERFS_IOC_*`) — `include/linux/reiserfs_fs.h`
4. device driver ioctls (e.g. `SCSI_IOCTL_*`) — `include/scsi/scsi_ioctls.h`
5. hardware device driver ioctls

The list (of actual ioctls — not this layer overview I present) would be quite... long. For hard disks and/or their partitions, `BLK*` is probably what you are looking for.